# rsync: how to relocate absolute symlinks?

Tags: rsync, symlink

I've pored over the rsync manpage as well as on several related questions here on serverfault. I've played with -R and -L and -l options, but no luck.

Here is the question: when sending a dir from local to remote, is there an option (or option combo) that relocates symlinks relative to the local dir so that they become relative to the destination dir on the remote machine?

Here is a minimal example of what I want to send:

**local dir:** `/home/bob/foo`

```
/home/bob/foo/a --> /home/bob/foo/bar
/home/bob/foo/bar
```

and here is how I would like it to materialize in the

**remote dir:** `/u/apps/foo`

```
/u/apps/foo/a --> /u/apps/foo/bar
/u/apps/foo/bar
```

For example, `rsync -az /home/bob/foo/ remote:/u/apps/foo/` doesn't quite do it; we end up with:

```
/u/apps/foo/a --> /home/bob/foo/bar
/u/apps/foo/bar
```

Whether `/home/bob/foo/bar` exists or not on the remote machine is irrelevant; in either case, the result is definitely not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the links are to absolute paths, no there's no way around it. You can get around it by making the symlinks relative:

```
/home/bob/foo/a --> ./bar
/home/bob/foo/bar
```

but that may prove difficult, depending on how you generate those links and how many of them there are.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I didn't realize the symlink was absolute, I thought it was just an effect of the way it was listed. After making the links relative, it all works out.  Next I'll think of a way to trawl the directories and relocate all the absolute symlinks found if they can be made relative to the topdir (in the example `/home/bob/foo`). Should be a perl one-liner.